# dynamic justgage value from soap

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap

I would like to display the value coming back from `$("#spanrWS_Measured").text(data[0]);` as my justgage value (currently 123). Any help would be great. Full code is below.

```
 <script src="scripts/raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/justgage.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(ajaxcall, 5000); // Call every 5 seconds
}); function ajaxcall(){
 $.ajax({
     url: 'soap.php',
     success: function(data) {
        data = data.replace('[','');
        data = data.replace(']','');
        data = data.split('|');

    // Status
    $("#spanrWS_Measured").text(data[0]);

     }
 }); }
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var g1;

           <!--Start G1->
    var g1 = new JustGage({
        id: "g1",
        value: 123,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        pointer: true,
        pointerOptions: {
        color: '#222D4B',
    },
        decimals: 1,
        startAnimationTime: 500,
        startAnimationType: ">",
        refreshAnimationTime: 1000,
        refreshAnimationType: "bounce",
        title: "",
        label: "mps",
        titleFontColor: "black",
        valueFontColor: "black",
        labelFontColor: "black",
        relativeGaugeSize: true,
         customSectors: [{
    color : "#00ff00",
    lo : 0,
    hi : 60
  },{
    color : "#ff0000",
    lo : 61,
    hi : 120
  }],

    });
     <!--End G1-->
       });
</script>
```

Comment: when you get the data call refresh function on gage reference var.like g1.refresh(10);

Comment: thanks. i used this in the end

    g2.refresh(data[1]);

Answer (score 1):

I used this in the end

```
   function ajaxcall(){
 $.ajax({
     url: 'soap.php',
     success: function(data) {
    data = data.replace('[','');
    data = data.split('|');

        // Dials
        g1.refresh(data[0]);
        g2.refresh(data[1]);
        g3.refresh(data[2]);
```